# How to test what has been outputted to the console

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I am attempting to create JUnit tests that can verify what has been printed to the console, for a console-based Java program.

As a very simple example:

If I had the following function and called it, how would I verify the output to console with JUnit?

```
void printMessage(String mess){
    System.out.println("Blah blah blah");
}
```

I have attempted using StringWriter and PrintWriter to pass byte streams, however, ideally I would not want to have to pass extra parameters to my functions to enable the tests to pass when I would not require the parameters for the function itself to operate.